# Sound freezes (beeping) - sound blaster x-fi HD

Tags: soundcard, sound-blaster

I have the problem that after listening to the music (about 15 minutes), 
the only sound coming out is a beep sound. If i plug off the usb, and insert it again, everything is okay. Have anyone experiented this problem?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Problem: Sound Blaster X-FI USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pulseaudio -k`, followed by `pulseaudio`, run in a terminal.

If that fails, try sticking the text in the following link in a shell script called `alsacontrol.sh`(Using text editor), making it executable from the permissions tab when you right-click it, and then run it when needed by opening a terminal and running `./alsacontrol.sh`:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1094899/

How this works:

Pulseaudio is a layer used for bringing sound from most applications to ALSA, which then works with hardware. If Pulseaudio is hanging, then pulseaudio can be restarted. If ALSA is malfunctioning, you may restart ALSA using the second script.

Reference(Script moved to Pastebin in case source is down): http://ccrma-mail.stanford.edu/pipermail/planetccrma/2007-July/013484.html